# Are Career Questions on PM SE Considered On-Topic or Off-Topic

Tags: discussion, site-topic

This question is a career-advancement question:
[Are Functional Managers or Project Managers Better Candidates for Executive-Level Positions?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/are-functional-managers-or-project-managers-better-candidates-for-executive-level)

Some career advancement questions could be asked by posters who wish to enter project management, while other questions could be asked by posters who may wish to advance their career beyond project management.

Do questions such as this benefit our site?  Where do we draw the line on career-oriented questions?  Do we need to draw a line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, as long as the career we discuss is related to project management, questions are on-topic.

On the old site there was a question about transition from project management to product management (http://askaboutprojects.com/questions/1330/moving-from-project-management-to-product-management) which, for me, would be perfectly fine to have here. It is most on career but the context is definitely project management so it suits here.

Btw: I wouldn't like to see PM.SE heading to a place where only very narrow range of questions can be asked. Project management starts in one-man projects and ends up with leading huge programs of thousands of people. Yes, we're probably biased toward software development projects at the moment but I guess it was to be expected.

Anyway, if we want to have a site where people come to get their questions answered we shouldn't close ourselves for different topics and PM careers is one of them.

Comment: I'm right there with you.  PM is a broad subject, and there aren't many questions that have truly been off-topic so far.  I have a friend who is a PM coordinating the closure of old coal mines.  I've tried to encourage her to come here so that there is less of a bias towards software and more great examples of non-software PM questions.